# Doesn't VisualStudio 2015 come with proper tooling for writing unit tests for a .NET Core app?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

When I add a Unit Test project to a Solution with a .NET Core 1 web app (a RESTful API) and try to make it reference the .NET Core app project, I get the following error message:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> A reference to 'WebApplication1' could not be added. An assembly must have a 'dll' or 'exe' extension in order to be referenced.

Is this supposed to be possible?
Visual Studio, in this case, is Visual Studio 2015 with the "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2" installed.

Comment: What version of .NET Core 1 are you using? Certain versions of .NET Core 1.x (and all 2.x) are incompatible with VS 2015.

Comment: I'm using .NET Core 1.1.